# WPF Stack Panel show hide children

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a stackpanel with two radio buttons. One is Option A and the other Option B. Only one is selectable at a time. When I check option B, I want to display a couple of text boxes right below Option B radiobuttion and within the stack panel. And when I select Option A again the textboxes should not be visible.  How can I accompalish this by just using XAML?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534208/binding-to-a-wpf-togglebuttons-ischecked-state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only in XAML without even the Converter. Define ControlTemplate in your resources like

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonContent">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,202">
                <RadioButton x:Name="OptionA" Content="OptionA" />
                <RadioButton x:Name="OptionB" Content="OptionB" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" 
                     Visibility="Visible"
                     Text="My Textbox"  Margin="0,65,165,167"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=OptionB, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="MyTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and use it like

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonContent}"/>
```

hope it helps..

Answer (score 3):

You can bind to the `RadioButton` `IsChecked` property and use the built-in `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400" Name="UI" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,202">
            <RadioButton x:Name="OptionA" Content="OptionA" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="OptionB" Content="OptionB" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox Visibility="{Binding ElementName=OptionB, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Text="My Textbox"  Margin="0,65,165,167"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

This will show the `TextBox` only when "OptionB" is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code Hope will solve your proble.

Put the TextBoxes in a stack panel and set the Visibility property of stack panel is Hidden.
and write the code on OptionButton event to set the Visibility property of stackPanel.

> 

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="33*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="33*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="33*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <StackPanel Margin="20" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <RadioButton Name="rdA" Content="Option A" GroupName="txtBoxGroup" Checked="rdA_Checked"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Name="rdB" Content="Option B" GroupName="txtBoxGroup" Checked="rdB_Checked"></RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Margin="20" Name="TxtBxStackPanel" Height="auto"  Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Label Content="My TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Label>
        <TextBox Name="txtValue" Height="20" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

In code behid -

```
private void rdB_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    TxtBxStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
private void rdA_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TxtBxStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Enjoy !!!!!!

Thanks

Ck Nitin (TinTin)

Comment: Two problems.  First, the Visibility should probably be changed to Collapsed, not Hidden.  Second, this is not XAML only, as specifically requested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just have an event that when you select Option A, both of the `TextBoxes` get set to:

```
Textbox.Visibility = Collapsed or Hidden
```

depending on how you wish to display them.

Comment: True. I realised that a little while after posting.